# What combos can you get breeding sun dragons with others?

Tags: dragonvale

Can you breed sun dragons with others? Is it productive?

Answer (score 2):

The Sun Dragon can only be bred with a Solstice Dragon, an Equinox Dragon or another Sun Dragon. The Solstice and Equinox Dragons were limited edition dragons and are no longer available for buying or breeding. Unless you already have either of those, you can only breed your Sun Dragon with another one, and I'm pretty sure a Sun Dragon will be the outcome.

Comment: Ty I kinda figured ;)

Comment: Yeah, same dragon + same dragon always yields the same dragon, even if the elements could combine into a different dragon or it's a limited time dragon that's expired

Comment: The DragonVale Breeding Sandbox [suggests](http://www.2084.org/dragonvale/breeding-sandbox/) That breeding limited + limited results in a 50/50 split.  So Sun + Equinox/Solstice is not productive, but Soltice + Equinox could be, if you only had one of each.  I actually recently bread Sun + Solstice to get a Sun egg for display (since I only had one Sun dragon).  But, yeah - productive uses are few.

Comment: This answer is now out of date.  Sun can also be bred with Lunar and Solar Eclipse dragons.  It seems the Limited Sun dragons can be expected to make regular return appearances based on the calendar and actual celestial events - since this has already happened several times for Equinox, Solstice, and the Eclipse dragons.

Answer (score 1):

I think you will get a sun from breeding those. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I breed a solar eclipse with the equinox dragon and got a equinox I think 24hr the egg has a sun and moon on it.