# Is there a way to breed sun with moon on dragonvale

Tags: dragonvale

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What combos can you get breeding sun dragons with others?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/87293/what-combos-can-you-get-breeding-sun-dragons-with-others)

Can I breed sun with moon on dragonvale .if so what is the result.

Comment: The answer is a duplicate, though it does not say it directly, the question is not however.

Comment: @James The question very much is. The question linked specifically asks what dragons a Sun Dragon can breed with, while the answer clearly states the only two.